# Changing edited textbox value to the original passed value on clicking outside the div of textbox in reactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, events

Please refer the image attached first by clicking on [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy7Xj.png).
There is a textbox which retrieves the original value from the state. Now, if any user changes textbox's value and click's outside the div then the textbox value must be replaced with the original value obtained from the state i.e 2000 [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy7Xj.png). If the user clicks on edit after changing the value in the textbox then that value must be updated in the state.

Any suggestions to perform this task.
Code sample is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I found the solution that outside div onClick event you set state to original value and input div add onclick event stopPropagation so click on this div outside onClick event not called and edit button add onclick or onSubmit(if you use form) event for perform edit login.

Sample code is here.

```
        this.state = {
        flag: false,
        number: 0,
        oldNumber: 0
    }

    handleEditMaxAmount =()=>{
        // edit code here.
    }

    outClickHandle =()=>{
        if(this.state.flag){
          this.setState({
            number: oldNumber
          })
          this.state.flag = false
        }
    }

    inClickHandle =()=>{
        this.state.flag = true;
      }


    <div onClick={this.outClickHandle}>
        ...
        <div onClick={(e)=>{e.stopPropagation();}}>
            <input type="number" value={this.state.number} onChange={this.inClickHandle} name="number" />
            <button onClick={this.handleEditNumber}>Edit </button>     
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
```